# Merge fork-repo with another fork-repo which comes from the same source

Tags: git, gitlab

Suppose I have a repo called `project-a` and then create a fork out of it named `project-b`. In this case, I understand that we can merge the two of them in both direction.

Now I want to make another fork of `project-a`, and let's call it `project-c`. My question: is it possible to merge the new `project-c` *to* `project-b` (vice versa)? If it is, is this a safe practice or is there something that I need to be aware of?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: git (at least `git`, I don't know about what service providers _provide_) does not care about what repo something is coming from... all it cares about is the _commits_ that will be merged, no restrictions whatsoever.

Comment: In each of the forks (`project-a`, `project-b`, `project-c`) you can add the other repositories as remotes. Then you can fetch and merge from those other forks.

Comment: You do not merge forks of repositories. You merge commits (or branches). There are absolutley no restrictions by Git what you merge where. Any direction is good. Things are different if you use a Git hosting service and you restrict yourself to use only the facilities that they provide.

Comment: @eftshift0 In gitlab, when you create a fork, the repo will have "fork relation" to its source; though it can be removed. So based on what you say, does this "fork relation" is simply informational and not limiting its ability to merge or anything?

Comment: @j6t Ah, that clears it. Thanks!